# how python to Zip a list of list with a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to zip a list of list with a list? So for example you have the two lists:

```
a = [['a','b'],['c','d']], b = [1, 2].
```

And I want the result:

```
 c=[['a','b',1],['c','d',2].
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
c = [(A + [B]) for (A,B) in zip(a,b)]
```

**Output:**

> [['a', 'b', 1], ['c', 'd', 2]]

Comment: thanks @fountainhead, I used this method, but a little slow, my list is very long.

Answer (score 1):

(Suggesting alternative, as OP mentioned (in comments) that the list is long, and efficiency is a requirement).

You could modify the first list `a` **in-place**, with a plain `for` loop:

```
for sublist, e in zip(a,b):
    sublist.append(e)

print (a)
```

**Output:**

> [['a','b',1],['c','d',2]

(Note that this modifies the original list `a` by appending to the sub-lists within `a`.)